# Validar domínio preg_replace

Tags: php, regex

A minha dúvida é a seguinte, tenho a seguinte função:

```
$site = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_POST['site']);
```

Mas ao utilizar na string  ***www.lostscavenge.com.br***, essa expressão regular emite o seguinte retorno:
 **wwwlostscavengecombr**

Como faço para essa função permitir e não remover os pontos?

Comment: Como assim somente o uso do ponto?

Comment: Eu quero limpar a string, tirar todos os caracteres especiais, permitindo apenas o uso do ponto, por exemplo quando eu uso essa função e digito no formulário www.lostscavenge.com.br minha string fica assim:

wwwlostscavengecombr

Sendo que era pra ficar assim:
www.lostscavenge.com.br

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nomes de domínio atualmente podem podem ser unicode (utf8). Dependendo das regras do seu business model, caso necessite permitir domínios que possuam caracteres não ASCII, a rotina abaixo pode ser útil:

```
function validate_domain_name($str, $force_utf8 = true)
{
    $force_utf8 = $force_utf8? 'u': '';

    //Isso é ineficiente.
    //$re = '[^a-zA-Z0-9\.]';

    //Isso é ineficiente. Pois não valida normas básicas
    //$re = '^(http[s]?\:\/\/)?((\w+)\.)?(([\w-]+)?)(\.[\w-]+){1,2}$';

    //Esse é mais consistente
    $re = '^(?!\-)(?:[\w\d\-]{0,62}[\w\d]\.){1,126}(?!\d+)[\w\d]{1,63}$';

    if (preg_match('/'.$re.'/'.$force_utf8, $str, $rs) && isset($rs[0]) && !empty($rs[0])) {
        return $rs[0];
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

$str = '000-.com';
$str = '-000.com';
$str = '000.com'; // válido
$str = 'foo-.com';
$str = '-foo.com';
$str = 'foo.com'; // válido
$str = 'foo.any'; // válido
$str = 'お名前0.com'; // válido
$str = 'お名前.コム'; // válido

echo 'domain: '.validate_domain_name($str);
```

Para desabilitar o unicode, defina o segundo parâmetro como booleano `false`.

A expressão regular original foi adaptada a partir dessa resposta: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16491074/1685571

As adaptações que fiz foi trocar `a-zA-Z` por `\w` e adicionar a opção para incluir a flag `u`, a qual permite caracteres non-ASCII.

Answer (score 1):

Basta adicionar o ponto ao seu padrão:

```
$site = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\.]/", "", $_POST['site']);
```

É esse `\.` no fim do padrão. A `\` é para escapar o ponto (.), porque em expressões regulares o `.` significa qualquer caractere

Comment: Opa, deu certo aqui porém eu não entendo de jeito nenhum essas expressões mas tem alguns sites que tem o traço também - então acho que não daria muito certo.. será que dá pra permitir o uso dele também?

Comment: Sim, basta adicionar o `-` no final. Ele não precisa ser escapado. Na verdade, dentro de colchetes não há necessidade de escapar nada, nem o ponto, mas eu gosto de fazer isso, é um hábito. Sua nova expressão ficaria: `$site = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]/", "", $_POST['site']);`

Comment: Obrigado, deu certo!

Comment: @ViniciusAquino segue uma referencia sobre as expressões regulares, para que possa compreende-las melhor :) http://www.devmedia.com.br/expressoes-regulares-em-php/25076

Comment: @leo_ap quanto está dentro de colchetes o ponto não é um meta caractere, logo sua regex está escapando a barra invertida também. O correto é`'/[^a-zA-Z0-9.]/'`

Comment: @gmsantos de forma alguma, se colocar a barra invertida causa um erro na expressão regular, para fazer o match dela deve-se usar \\ em qualquer situação, dentro ou fora de colchetes. O `\.` dentro de colchetes escapa corretamente o ponto.

Comment: @leo_ap http://regexr.com/3f2mn http://stackoverflow.com/a/15139411/2099835

Comment: [.] e [\.] irão fazer o match apenas do ponto. para fazer o match de uma barra invertida e de um ponto seria necessário: [\\.] (ou também [\\\.]). Compreenda que a barra invertida faz o escapamento do caractere seguido dela em qualquer situação.

Comment: Se usar uma string simples no PHP (com aspas simples) a barra invertida é considerada. Uma coisa é como a linguagem escapa os caracteres, outra coisa é a expressão regular em si.

Comment: @gmsantos Estou me referindo exatamente ao comportamento da expressão regular em si, o que estou a dizer é a forma como ela foi elaborada e concebida pelos seus idealizadores e pela grande maioria de seus implementadores. Usar uma barra invertida sozinha dentro de colchetes irá causar erro na maioria das implementações de expressão regular. Isso porque dentro de colchetes a barra invertida é considerada um metacaracter.